# How To add striped or Slant Line to progressbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i design a Progressbar like

```
<style>
    #progress-holder{width:400px;height:20px;background:grey}
    #progress{width:0;height:100%;background:black}
</style>
<div id="progress-holder">
   <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
<script>
   var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
   function updateValue(perc) {
      progress.style.width = perc+'%';
   }
updateValue(40);
</script>
```

its simple and with updateValue() function i can change progress value
... now i want to add a **slant Line** to this progressbar like [image]

Do you know something like that? Or an existing script? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap. Bootstrap lets you define a progress bar very easily. Check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress).
Note it is not available in IE9 and below.

If you want to use Css3 see [this link](http://red-team-design.com/stylish-css3-progress-bars/)

Comment: can you suggest a way with pure javascript?